# Prove Set is Dedekind Cut

Tags: real-analysis, dedekind-domain

Let $G$ be a Dedekind cut. Show that

$H = \{x \in \mathbb{Q} : $There exists $a \in Q_{>0}$ such that $-x-a \not \in G \}$

Prove that $H$ is a Dedekind cut.

I'm not entirely sure where to begin with this especially since Dedekind cuts are new to me. How would I be able to use the definition of $H$ to prove this?

The Dedekind cut definition is defined as follows:
A Dedekind cut $d \subset \mathbb{Q}$ has the following properties:

1. $d \neq \mathbb{Q}$
2. $a \in d, b < a \implies b \in d$ (downward closure)
3. $\forall a \in d, \exists b \in d$ such that $b>a$ (No greatest element)

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: There are slightly different ways to define a **Dedekind** (not dedikind) cut. Which one are you working with?

Comment: Your definition is missing $d \ne \emptyset$, since that doesn't follow from 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

Lets prove first that $H\ne \emptyset$. Assume $H = \emptyset$. That would mean that for all $x \in \Bbb Q$ doesn't exists $a\in\Bbb Q_{>0}$ such that $-x-a\not\in G$. In particular, for all $x\in \Bbb Q$ we have $-x-1 \in G$, so $G = \Bbb Q$, a contradiction. So $H \ne \emptyset$.

Lets prove now that $H \ne \Bbb Q$. Assume that $H = \Bbb Q$. Since $G \ne \emptyset$, choose any $y \in G$. There exist $x \in \Bbb Q = H$ such that $-x < y$, but then exists $a \in \Bbb Q_{>0}$ such that $-x-a \not\in G$, but $-x-a<-x<y \in G$, this contradicts downward closure of $G$.

Can you continue with the next two properties to prove that $H$ is a Dedekind cut?

Hint: The idea is that if $G$ represents the real number $r$, $H$ represents the real number $-r$.

Comment: I'm having trouble proving property 2. If $G$ is a Dedekind cut then it must have downward closure. Suppose it's closed by $m$. Doesn't that mean that any value $<m$ could be in $H$? Hence, $m$ might actually represent some upper bound and we don't have downward closure? @jjagmath

Comment: "Suppose it's closed by $m$". What do you mean by that? "Downward closure" means that if the set have an element $x$, it also have all the elements less than $x$.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. Thanks again for your response!